# Using Spring MockMvc Tests to hit Real Server

Tags: spring, integration-testing, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

Is it possible to use `MockMvc` test code to hit a real instance of a web application?

I really like the `MockMvc` syntax and after going to the efforts of writing a load of code to test controllers, it seems like a duplication of effort to rewrite what would effectively be the same tests using a different API just so I can make an *actual* HTTP request.

I've got some situations where my `MockMvc` tests pass, but then the tested behaviour fails when deployed to a web container. This is normally a configuration or environmental issue, and it'd be nice to be able to repeat the same tests to flush those out.

Answer (score 1):

MockMvc is about testing the Controller Layer and it works like a charm .

I think you need Selenium tests to test against a real, deployed application.

Using **webdriver** (With phantomjs) guarantees that you have the *same* ease of use as you get with Spring MVC.

But you will have to rewrite your tests to work with webdriver+phantomjs.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to re-use the same tests.